# Cant Open .Storyboard in Visual Studio Xamarin using mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xcode9.3

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB6I5.png)

Im currently using visual studio xamarin on mac and the latest version of Xcode 9.3

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Can this storyboard file be opened in XCode?

Comment: Yes, it just every time I create a new one it needs to be open in Xcode Interface builder first. i dunno why

Comment: Then what's the version of your vs for mac. Also whether each storyboard cannot be opened? Can you share a simple error file? Let me see it in my side.